# Rails - Remove Timestamps From JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, active-model-serializers, serialization

I'm using AMS to create JSON output for my Rails API. Currently, when it renders the list of blogs. The timestamps for the Users are still being shown in my output, even though it does not exist in my serializer.

Blog Serializer:

```
class BlogSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :user
  has_many :posts
end
```

User Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :username
end
```

Blog Controller:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all

    render json:  @blogs
  end
end
```

Why are the timestamps still being rendered for the User?

Comment: Show your controller pls

Comment: you try restarting the server?

Comment: @MikhailKatrin added

Comment: @inye yup! didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify serializer

Add `each_serializer: BlogSerializer` to `render json`

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @blogs = Blog.all

        render json:  @blogs, each_serializer: BlogSerializer 
    end
end
```

And how `User` associated with `Blog`?

Comment: Blog -- belongs_to :poster, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "poster_id"   User-- has_many: blogs

Comment: You should add all associations to serializers too